# MVC Deployment - Relative Path issue with respect to Application Path

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

While deploying my MVC Project, I have faced an issue of relative path w.r.t server.
I am hosting the project as an application in IIS. Finally the url to my application will look like `http://localhost/portal/Account/Login` here 'portal' is the application name in IIS. In the ASP.net development server everything was working fine. while deploying it needed the relative path with respect to server. Because of this my jquery ajax requests started failing.
To fix this issue I kept the actions in hidden field and accessing from there and using for ajax request. The following is the code.

```
 <input type="hidden" value="@Url.Action("GetNewOffersSearch", "Updates")" id="NewOffersSearchUrl" />

var NewoffersUrl = document.getElementById("NewOffersSearchUrl").value;


 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: NewoffersUrl ,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 10000,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (_results) {
                $("#updatesContent").html(_results);
            },
            error: function (_results) {

            }
        });
```

Initially NewoffersUrl was `"/Updates/GetNewOffersSearch"` and  it was throwing a path error. But now it is `"/portal/Updates/GetNewOffersSearch"` and its working fine

I just want to know the approach I am following is correct or not. Is there any better fixes for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way we do `AJAX` requests is similiar, however we pass the URL directly to the url parameter of the ajax call rather than using a hidden field.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: @Url.Action("GetNewOffersSearch", "Updates"),
        cache: false,
        timeout: 10000,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (_results) {
            $("#updatesContent").html(_results);
        },
        error: function (_results) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Its working fine. But the Visual Studio intellisense finding it as something unusual.

Comment: amesh - you can have to use ' round the @Url.Action.  For instance: '@Url.Action("GetNewOffersSearch", "Updates")',